# html DOM program to find href value

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am a newbie in php and I have been assigned with a project to fetch the HREF value from the following HTML snippet:

```
<p class="title">

<a href="http://canon.com/">Canon Pixma iP100 + Accu Kit

</a>

</p>
```

Now for this am using the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $link) {
    # Show the <a href>
    foreach($link->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link)
    {
            echo $link->getAttribute('href');
            echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

This code gives me the HREF value of all `<a href>` from all the `<P>` tag in that page. I want to parse the `<P>` with the class "title" only...I can't use Simple_HTML_DOM or any kind of library here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use `DOMXpath` for this one. Like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// target p tags with a class with "title" with an anchor tag
$target_element = $xpath->query('//p[@class="title"]/a');
if($target_element->length > 0) {
    foreach($target_element as $link) {
        echo $link->getAttribute('href'); // http://canon.com/
    }
}
```

Or If if you want to traverse it. Then you need to have to search it manually.

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $p) {
    // if p tag has a "title" class
    if($p->getAttribute('class') == 'title') {
        foreach($p->childNodes as $child) {
            // if has an anchor children
            if($child->tagName == 'a' && $child->hasAttribute('href')) {
                echo $child->getAttribute('href'); // http://cannon.com
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a ton! just a small query if I want to fetch the text value of the <a> tag means "Canon Pixma iP100 + Accu Kit"...what should I have to do?

Comment: @JoyeetaSinharay if you want that you can use `$child->nodeValue`, it should get the text